# difference in using multi level inheritance in scala and using all the levels in 1 level by using "with" keyword

Tags: scala, traits, extends

I am a java developer and learnt scala recently. Can anybody help to understand this confusion.

suppose i am having the below code structure.

```
abstract class A {
  val message: String
}
class B extends A {
  val message = "I'm an instance of class B"
}
trait C extends A {
  def loudMessage = {message.toUpperCase()}
}
class D extends B with C
```

now the question is about last line of code : when we are extending class B in D, B is already containing the members of class A. Why we should write like this ? Is there any difference ?

Thanks a lot for even reading my question. For the person who is thinking and answered, hats off.

Comment: as for me this case doesn't have any difference in compare to interface `C` with `default implementation`  of method `loudMessage` in java8+. In java it would be `class D extends B implements C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference, since extending class B, you got the message part, further on mixing in trait C which also needed message, but we already have it from B and now we have the loudMessage from C as well.

Copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#Mitigation)-

> a class can only inherit from a single class, but can mix-in as many
>   traits as desired. Scala resolves method names using a right-first
>   depth-first search of extended 'traits', before eliminating all but
>   the last occurrence of each module in the resulting list.

this resolves the diamond problem (multiple inheritance).

It's a general practice to write in traits and mix them in your classes whenever necessary, you'll find them interestingly useful when writing unit tests, create a lot a of fake data/ mocks in traits and mix them in whenever.